# asychronous function in loop javascript nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-maps, httprequest

I need to scan the trip array and calculate the travel time between the current trip with each trip in the array and select the shortest one. For calculation i need to send google maps api call.

I am very confused about the asynchronous callback function .
Can anyone help me on this how to send api call within for loop and check the results and continue?

Thank you.

The trips are in my array list;

**Array :**

```
array=[trip1,trip2, trip3,....];
```

**JS :**

```
function assigntrips(array){

var triplist = [];
for(var i=0; i< array.length; i++){

        var fstnode = array[i];
        for(var j=i+1; j<array.length; j++){
            //here i want to get the response from google api and decide if i want to choose the trip. 
           if not the for loop continues and send another api call.

        }

    }
}


function apicall(inputi, cb){
var destination_lat = 40.689648;
var destination_long = -73.981440;


var origin_lat = array[inputi].des_lat;
var origin_long = array[inputi].des_long;

var departure_time = 'now';

    var options = { 
            host: 'maps.googleapis.com',

            path: '/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins='+ origin_lat    +','+origin_long+ '&destinations=' + office_lat + ',' + office_long + '&mode=TRANSIT&departure_time=1399399424&language=en-US&sensor=false'

        }

 http.get(options).on('response',function(response){
        var data = '';

        response.on('data',function(chunk){
            data += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end',function(){
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(json);
            var ttltimereturnoffice = json.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
        //var node = new Node(array[i],null, triptime,0,ttltimereturnoffice,false); 
        //tripbylvtime.push(node);
        cb(ttltimereturnoffice + '\t' + inputi);
        });


        });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check the results in the loop. The loop is in the past, the callbacks happen in the future - you can't change that. There are only two things you can do, and one is an abstraction of the other:

1) You can create your callback in such a manner that it will collect the results and compare them when all are present.

2) You can use promises to do the same thing.

The #1 approach would look something like this (while modifying the `cb` call in your code appropriately):

```
var results = [];
function cb(index, ttltimereturnoffice) {
  results.push([index, ttltimereturnoffice]);
  if (results.length == array.length) {
    // we have all the results; find the best one, display, do whatever
  }
}
```

I don't quite know what library you are using, and if it supports promises, but if `http.get` returns a promise, you can do #2 by collecting the promises into an array, then using the promise library's `all` or `when` or similar to attach a callback on all `get`s being done.

Comment: if i want to use the element in the array and send it to api and then check the first api response and then decide if i want to send another api with the next element in the array, i can't do this ?

Comment: @ChloéLinHe You can do that, but it would require chaining requests to the callback. `function cb(){if(test){doAnotherQuery()}}`, and `doAnotherQuery` has the `cb` callback.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not understand that from your question. Of course you can do that; but in that case, you can't use a loop. I will sketch an answer in a bit. EDIT: @bcdan has it right.

Comment: @bcdan thanks, then how can i stop and go back to the outer loop when i think i am done with the api call in the inner loop?

Comment: @amadan thank you. I am trying to learn how to use promises. but it's quite confusing. can you give an example on how to use promise with the loop? i am using nodejs and i think it supports promises otherwise i could use promise api or q library

Comment: You can't. Whatever data you get in callbacks can only be used from callbacks. Again, the loop is in the past, the callback is in the future, and JavaScript only does time travel in one direction, like the rest of us.

Comment: Can you tell me which library is `http.get` from? Also, if you are doing conditional execution, straight-up callbacks might be cleaner. Also, promises are just a clever abstractions of callbacks, so understanding callbacks will be better for you in the long run.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out, it's the basic Node 'http.get`, and it does not return a promise.